# Finding the value of supply voltage in this RLC circuit

Tags: capacitor, resistors, ac, impedance, homework

[image: Circuit Diagram with Supply Voltage Value not provided]

We need to find the value of *V*, *Power Factor*, and *Power Absorbed* in the circuit.

I am stuck at resolving the two parallel branches.

I started out by labeling the impedances of the three given Resistance - Inductor/Capacitor pairs only to get stuck because the frequency is not provided.

Please give me a hint here.

Comment: Find the complex impedance as a function of frequency: Hint: Zc=1/(sC) and ZL=sL, with s=iω (or jω if you prefer).

Comment: @Bart And then proceed to find out the total z like we solve series and parallel circuits?

Comment: If you don't know F and you don't know V then you can't solve it.

Comment: @Andyaka by assuming f as 50Hz(maybe, the professor missed it?), I was able to solve for V. I don't know whether this counts or not

Comment: @Doodoo28 yes, and then multiply it by 15A to find the driving voltage of the circuit as a function of ω.